# How to manage additional processed data in MarkLogic

Tags: indexing, marklogic, data-processing

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

We have around 20M records in MarkLogic.

For one of the business requirement, we need to generate additional data for each xml and then need user will search this data.

As we can't change original document, so need input on what is best way to manage additional data. Following are the few which we have thought of

1. Create separate collection and store additional data in separate xml with same unique number i.e. same as original xml. So when user search for it, search in this collection and then retrieved original documents and send response back.
2. Store additional data in original document properties

We also need to create element range index to make sure it works when end user provide data in range operators.

```
<abc>
        <xyz>
          <quan>qty1</quan>
          <value1>1.01325E+05</value1>
          <unit>Pa</unit>
        </xyz>
        <xyz>
          <quan>qty2</quan>
          <value1>9.73E+02</value1>
          <value2>1.373E+03</value2>
          <unit>K</unit>
        </xyz>
        <xyz>
          <quan>qty3</quan>
          <value1>1.8E+03</value1>
          <unit>s</unit>
        </xyz>
        <xyz>
          <quan>qty4</quan>
          <value1>3.6E+03</value1>
          <unit>s</unit>
        </xyz>
</abc>
```

We need to process data from value1 element. User will then search for something like

- qty**1** >= minvalue AND qty**1**<=maxvalue
- qty**2** >= minvalue AND qty**2**<=maxvalue
- qty**3** >= minvalue AND qty**3**<=maxvalue

So when user will search for qty1 then it should only get data from  element where value is qty1 and so on.
So would like to know

- What is best approach to store data like this
- What kind of index i should create to implement this

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend wrapping the original data in an envelope, which allows adding extra data in the header. It could also allow creating a canonical view on the relevant pieces of the data, and either store that as instance, and original as 'attachment' (sub-property, not an attached binary), or keep the instance as-is, and put canonical values for indexing in the header.

There is a lengthy blog article about the topic, that discusses pros and cons in high detail: https://www.marklogic.com/blog/envelope-design-pattern/

HTH!

Comment: Hello Grtjn, Thanks for quick response. Does it requires to change to existing data? can we create element range index on data in headers ? how about performance ?

Comment: @ManishJoisar The header is just an XML doc, so yes.

Comment: The entire envelope can be either XML or JSON, depending on what is most convenient for you. If you have XML data, then use an XML envelope. Performance is most optimal, since there is no need for a join between fragments/documents.

Comment: You have to store your original data in a different way, so yes you have to change what you currently have in the database, but wrapping in an envelope would be the default approach if you use our Data Hub approach.

Comment: Your original data, and anything extra you add will form one large document, from which you can extract original data very easily if you make sure to keep it around. Indexes will work on the entire envelope, unless you use scoped queries, or path indexes that focus on particular parts.

Answer (score 1):

Grtjn's answer would be the recommended solution, as it is more performant to keep all the information inside the document itself, versus having to query across both the document with the properties, but it would require changes to the document.

Option 1 & 2 could both work.

Properties documents already exist, so it doesn't add fragments, but the properties must [conform to the schema](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#id_85728).

Creating a sidecar document provides more flexibility, because you are creating new documents, it will increase number of fragments.

Comment: With default settings, no properties fragments are created. So using properties would double the number of fragments.

Comment: It is true that properties follow a certain format, but you will notice that you can push a lot inside, including complete XML trees. Just keep in mind that it is XML, so inserting binary or json is less convenient.

Comment: If you really don't want to change the original docs, and you only have small pieces of extra data, consider using hidden metadata fields.

Comment: Added additional data in properties and search is working, so now question is, whatever implementation (search capabilities) we can do on original document, can we do the same for properties also?

Comment: For the most part, I believe so. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for your reply. When i added <constraint name="Properties"><properties/></constraint>, it worked, will it also work with bucket search?

Comment: It would be good if we can get examples with this kind of search, we do not found any good examples in ML documentation